# Simple WHERE clause breaking sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a working query here:

```
SELECT tlt.name AS theme, COUNT(*) AS nsets
    FROM tlt
    INNER JOIN sets
    ON tlt.id = sets.theme_id
    GROUP BY tlt.name
    ORDER BY nsets DESC;
```

But when I add a WHERE clause sqlite throws a syntax error "near" the WHERE clause

```html
SELECT tlt.name AS theme, COUNT(*) AS nsets
    FROM tlt
    INNER JOIN sets
    ON tlt.id = sets.theme_id
    GROUP BY tlt.name
    WHERE nsets > 50
    ORDER BY nsets DESC;
```

I'm confused why this simple WHERE clause breaks this query.

Comment: You need to go with `having count` or  `WHERE COUNT(*) > 50`

Comment: @jishansiddique I've tried that. Both of those also produce the same syntax error.

Comment: Please go with `SELECT tlt.name AS theme, COUNT(*) AS nsets
    FROM tlt
    INNER JOIN sets
    ON tlt.id = sets.theme_id
    GROUP BY tlt.name
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 50
    ORDER BY nsets DESC;`

Answer (score 5):

A `WHERE` clause must be before `GROUP BY`, not after. But you cannot use an alias or an aggregate function in a `WHERE` clause, so you need to use `HAVING COUNT(*) > 50` where you currently have your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT tlt.name AS theme, COUNT(*) AS nsets
FROM tlt
INNER JOIN sets
ON tlt.id = sets.theme_id
GROUP BY tlt.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 50
ORDER BY nsets DESC;
```